# Inserting values into a table within a function receives an error, but when trying to insert values into the table outside of a function it works fine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So this method works in inserting values to the table:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("example.com","a","b","c");
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ("foo", "bar");';
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

However, this method fails:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("example.com","a","b","c");
function foobar(){
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ("foo", "bar");';
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);  
}
```

And this gives the error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in foo/bar/example.php
```

I need to use the mysqli query inside a function as I am looping through multiple values. How do I fix this?

Comment: function foobar($link) ... you have to pass the variable into your function if you want to use it.

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you don't have $link variable in the function scope. (Meaning $link is null)
You can pass your connection resource to your function as a parameter (which is $link variable in your case) or use global.

passing connection resource as a parameter will be like :

```
$link = mysqli_connect("example.com","a","b","c");
 function foobar($link){
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ("foo", "bar");';
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("example.com","a","b","c");
function foobar($link){
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ("foo", "bar");';
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);  
}
```