# issue with mysqli query when I use the function to run the query

Tags: php, mysqli

Why do I get this error when I run a query using mysqli within a function? It works fine outside of the function. when running the function, the error states that the "$db" variable is undefined.

```
<?php

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'rocketforce_blog');



    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
    $row = $result->num_rows;
    $cnt = count($row);
    echo $cnt;

//=======================================================================================

    function user_exists($username, $password)
    {
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
        $row = $result->num_rows;
        $cnt = count($row);
        return $cnt;
    }

    echo user_exists($username, $password);

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting values into a table within a function receives an error, but when trying to insert values into the table outside of a function it works fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294450/inserting-values-into-a-table-within-a-function-receives-an-error-but-when-tryi)

Answer (score 1):

[The variable $db is not known in the scope of this function](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). If you want it to be known in this function, you either have to pass $db as parameter to the function. eg

```
function user_exists($db, $username, $password)
{
   $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
    $row = $result->num_rows;
    $cnt = count($row);
    return $cnt;
}

echo user_exists($db, $username, $password);
```

Or you import the global $db variable into the scope of the function. Like that:

```
function user_exists($username, $password)
{
   global $db;
   $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
    $row = $result->num_rows;
    $cnt = count($row);
    return $cnt;
}

echo user_exists($username, $password);
```

The first one is the better one, as you could use type hints, pass different connections and so on...